# How to execute Playwright .NET tests in Azure pipeline (Linux agent) in headed mode?

Tags: playwright, linux, azure-devops, .net

As per [Playwright .NET documentation](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/ci#running-headed), to run tests in Azure Pipelines using headed mode, you need to specify `xvfb-run` before `dotnet test` if using a Linux agent.

However, in terms of the YAML configuration, what I have been using is something like this (when I was using Selenium):

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.runTests }}', 'true')
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '${{ variables.MyTestProject }}'
    arguments: '--no-restore --logger "console;verbosity=normal" --filter "Category=MyCategory"'
  env:
    URL: ${{ variables.URL }}
    UserName: ${{ variables.UserName }}
    Password: '$(Secret-Password)'
```

Now I'm migrating to Playwright, this works fine in headless mode. But in headed mode, I can't find a way to pass the `xvfb-run` command before `dotnet test`.

I've tried a custom command here, instead of `test`, and set it to be `xvfb-run test` (and variations on this). However, the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task appends `dotnet` to the front of the command. So every time, it breaks.

I've also tried general Bash/script tasks to supply my own command. This appeared to work initially - something like this:

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: xvfb-run dotnet test --no-restore --logger "console;verbosity=normal" --filter "Category=MyCategory"
  env:
    URL: ${{ variables.URL }}
    UserName: ${{ variables.UserName }}
    Password: '$(Secret-Password)'
```

However, the tests then did not get supplied the variables I need - URL, Username and Password etc. So the tests tried to run in headed mode, but then failed due to null variables.

Anyone have any idea how I can pass `xvfb-run` *and* supply variables to my tests in this pipeline setup?

---

Assuming the variables are being passed in, I wondered if my approach of accessing them in-code was wrong. I've tried 2 approaches - neither of which have worked:

```cs
_scenarioContext.Add("UserName", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Applications:UserName"));
```

And this way:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true).AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
_scenarioContext.Add("UserName", config["Applications:UserName"]);
```

Comment: What you've shown _should_ work, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines#examples

Comment: I've added an update with some further info - I wondered if the issue was actually the way in which I retrieve the variables in my test code.

Comment: Apologies - please can you resubmit them? I must've missed the update.

Comment: Accepted those edits now - sorry about that. Early morning syndrome on a Friday!

Comment: I've been able to switch to a Windows agent, so my immediate issue has resolved itself (I no longer need the ```xvfb-run``` element). I will keep this question open as I'm still curious about the solution!